# Revslider error. Impossible to enter admin dashboard

Tags: fatal-error

No way to enter site admin's dashboard, cause revslider error. :-(

How can I fix it?

This is the wordpress message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/pikarte7/public_html/boudoir-valencia.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php:71 Stack trace: #0 /home/pikarte7/public_html/boudoir-valencia.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(572): RevSliderBaseAdmin::addMetaBox('Revolution Slid...', '', Array, NULL) #1 /home/pikarte7/public_html/boudoir-valencia.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(73): RevSliderAdmin->addSliderMetaBox() #2 /home/pikarte7/public_html/boudoir-valencia.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/revslider-admin.class.php(44): RevSliderAdmin->init() #3 /home/pikarte7/public_html/boudoir-valencia.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(162): RevSliderAdmin->__construct('/home/pikarte7/...') #4 /home/pikarte7/public_html/boudoir-valencia.com/wp-settings.php(360): include_once('/home/pikarte7/...') #5 /home/pikarte7/public_html/boudoir-valencia.com/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/home/pikart in /home/pikarte7/public_html/boudoir-valencia.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/base-admin.class.php on line 71

Comment: Go to your wordpress installation Folder with your favorite FTP client and search for the revslider plugin folder inside wp-content/plugins. Move the revslider plugin folder somewhere else on your server. This should disable the plugin in general.

Comment: most likely revslider does not support your PHP version. generally `[]` is array shorthand that is supported by PHP 7+, but not in 5.x... update to PHP 7 or use another plugin, you can't keep fixing this on every plugin update and it may be used somewhere else in future.

Comment: @majick this is not correct. This shorthand was introduced in PHP 5.4.0 in March 2012. If he uses an older version, it's really time to update. ;o)

Comment: @moped Thanks for being more specific, well the logic was if others are not getting this error then it is likely due to old PHP version. other than that could be a corrupt plugin needs reinstalling. If that doesn't work then these kind of issues are best reported to directly to the plugin author.

Comment: Thank you for your help.